# how to change output mode to input mode (fields)in updating the database file using rpgle as400

Tags: function-pointers, rpgle

I've written a program in `#rpgle` along with the 2 records *work screen* in display file.

First record will display the main-screen-of-company, which takes input as:
`emp id` *indicators= `f3`: exit `f6`: accept*.

After pressing the *`f6`*, it goes to the second record
*indicators= `f3`: exit `f12`: cancel `f7`: modify `f8`: delete `f6`: accept*
& fields are in output mode.

When I press *`f7`* to update the fields, which are in o/p non editable mode should get change into editable mode.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try protecting the field with the same indicator associated to the function key.

```
A          R REC001                    TEXT('Record') 
A                                      CF07(07)                    
A            FIELD    R        B 10  3                            
A N07                                  DSPATR(PR)
```

Comment: Also, rewrite the record format so that the changed attribute is communicated to the display.